# Validate nickname with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I neet to validate a nick name without `@` and `#`and  it can't start with numbers

thi is my solution but the `@` and `#`

```
(^[^0-9])([\w a-z A-Z 0-9][^@#])
```

.test:

```
andrea //true
0andrea // false

// these are true but I need them to be false

and@rea // true
and#rea // true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your regex:

```
^(^[^0-9])([\w a-z A-Z 0-9][^@#])$
```

explained

1. dont start with a number.start with any thing other than numbers.
2. two letter upper/lower case or digit or underscore followed by any of `^@#`

SO according to your regex, any three letter word will be matched.

use this:

```
^[^0-9]\w+$
```

this will work for usernames not conatining any special chars.

If you specifically just not want @ and #. use this :

```
^[^0-9][^@#]+$
```

demo here : https://regex101.com/r/gV9eO0/1

Comment: thanks, could you explain why you need double `^` for the 1st expression?

Comment: i have not used double `^` the first ^ is position starting of string. the second ^ is inside `[]` which means exclude the contents inside `[]`.

Answer (score 4):

> I neet to validate a nick name without `@` and `#` and it can't start with numbers

Using `(!?pattern)` is a negative lookahead so you can prevent a `\d` as first char without preventing the rest of the expression from looking at it, then

If you're only blacklisting then

```
^(?!\d)[^@#]+$
```

[image: reg1]

Otherwise, use a whitelist

```
^(?!\d)[a-zA-z\d ]+$
```

[image: reg2]

Notice how we keep matching to the end of the string, `$`.
I've used `+` because you probably don't want to permit zero-length nicknames.

Also, you can sort-of go down the route you were attempting by using a `*` or `+` operator on a group;

```
^(?!\d)(?:(?![@#])[a-zA-Z\d ])+$
```

[image: reg3]

Graphical representations via [**debuggex.com**](https://www.debuggex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
^[a-zA-Z]\w*$
```

- `\w` is a shortcut for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, the alphanum class.
- `[a-zA-Z]` ensures your first character isn't a number (so your nickname can't be empty)
- `^$` are anchors matching the beginning and the end of the string, ensuring the string only contains the wanted characters